# Python: how to change font in a colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Let's suppose I would like to have ticklabel font in colorbar different from the rest of the plot. How would I do this?

Comment: This lacks context. What plot? What colorbar? What's a ticklabel?

Comment: Plot is an imshow image. Colorbar is related to that image. Tick labels that I am talking about are on the colorbar. I would like to use monospace font instead the default font.

Comment: There is no Python package called "imshow". If you are using matplotlib (which has a *function* called imshow) then please say so. Also show some code. Are we supposed to guess what you are doing?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance oh wise guru. But don't bother, Thorsten found the solution even though I couldn't explain the problem that well.

Comment: Always, whenever you ask a question anywhere with regards to programming include the following information: 1. What are you trying to achieve? 2. How are you trying to achieve it? 3. In what way does it not work? The best way to include this information is to include code that shows the problem and, if applicable, an error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about matplotlib, iterate over all ticklabels and set font family:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
cb = plt.colorbar()

for l in cb.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    l.set_family("Comic Sans MS")

plt.show()
```